# Can't open notes:// links in HCL Notes 12.0.1

Tags: url, lotus-notes

I am using HCL Notes 12.0.1 and Windows 11 Pro, I can't open links that I have dragged from a tab in Notes to a folder on my harddrive. also tried to enter the url into Edge/Chrome with same error

I have tried to run the notesw32.reg but that didn't help
If I enter the url in Notes address bar it works, but not from anywhere else

what can I do to resolve this?

anyone else having problem with this using 12.0.1?

[image]

Comment: Might be worth checking `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Notes`.  Does it exist?  Is the `(Default)` value `URL:notes`?  Does it have a `shell\open\command` sub-key with a `(Default)` value pointing to the correct drive:\folder\application.exe ?  If yes to all, then maybe try populating the optional `[server]` component of the [Notes URI scheme](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-dconmy-notes-uri-scheme-02.html) as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thx. The answer is yes to all. Didn’t follow what you mean with uri scheme, is that a file in Notes dir?

Comment: You'll notice 3 slashes in your **Notes:///** URL.  Typically, there's 2 slashes after **Notes:**, followed by a `server` reference, then another slash after that.  Try inserting either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` after the second slash.  Might not help, but worth a try.

Comment: thx, but didn't help